# Linux based OS Installation freezes at "Third Party Software Installation" Screen

Tags: linux, linux-mint, freeze

I have a Linux 18.1 Cinnamon 32-Bit Live USB Drive. It works perfectly fine. But when I click on "Install Linux Mint" the Installation screen freezes at the Second step ("Third Party Software Installation"). I have Internet connected and have tried both check and unchecking that option, but no luck !!!

After waiting for 10Minutes at the Installation Screen, I shutdown Linux and the following error screen appeared : 
[image: Error Screen]

I then Run a GParted Scan. The following is the Scan Result:

[image: GParted]

**Notice the Warning Icon preceding the selected Partition.**
Also notice it is the same "dev sda5" Partition on which I/O Error was reported during Linux Installation freezing.

On Clicking the Partition , I get the Following :

[image: Games Partition]

Please help me. I'm clueless as to why I/O Error is happening or why Linux Installation Freezes at all :(

**SYSTEM DETAILS :**

Processor : AMD Sempron (x86)
RAM       : 2GB
HDD       : 500 GB (I have 10 GB of unallocated Free Space)

**Update : It's not Linux Mint only. I also tried installing Lubuntu in my system. Same problem appearing!!!**

Comment: This is a hard drive error... either the disk is bad or the partition is corrupt. If this is a Windows partition, you need disable "Fast Startup" which is sometimes called "Hybrid Shutdown" in Windows and clean the error in Windows.

Comment: It's not a Windows partition. It's just a Logical 130GB partition